# How to start an AWS Ec2 instance via https using PHP?

Tags: php, sdk, https, amazon-web-services

I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP version 2 to start and stop an Ec2 instance.
How can i set the Ec2Client object (or what method should i choose) to use an https connection instead of http?

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not already using an https connection by default?

You can set the EC2 client to use either http or https using the "scheme" option when instantiating the client.

```
$client = Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => '<aws access key>',
    'secret' => '<aws secret key>',
    'region' => '<region name>',
    'scheme' => 'https',
));
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but i was not sure. Shuldn't i see the "https" label on my browser's address bar?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the connection from the SDK to the EC2 service. It seems what you are really wanting to know is how to configure an EC2 instance with an SSL cert. I don't think this is something you can do with the SDK alone. You can use the SDK to configure your instance's security group to make sure ports 22 and 443 are open, but that does not install an SSL cert on the instance for you. I would try asking on the [EC2 user forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30) for more help.